# Converting from a Uint8Array to an ArrayBuffer prepends 32 bytes?

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer

Consider the input *bytes* that is  a 400byte *Uint8Array*. The following code converts it first to an *ArrayBuffer* via the *.buffer* method and subsequently to a *Float32Array* :

```
  static bytesToFloatArray(bytes) {
      let buffer = bytes.buffer; // Get the ArrayBuffer from the Uint8Array.
      let floats = new Float32Array(buffer);
      return floats
  }
```

The surprise is that the conversion to the *ArrayBuffer* prepends 32 bytes - which is reflected in having 8 extra "0" float values at the beginning of the subsequent *Float32Array* :

[image]

Why does the *buffer* method add the 32 bytes - and how can that be avoided (or corrected) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the buffer method add the 32 bytes?

It didn't. The buffer had 432 bytes in the first place, even before the `Uint8Array` was created on it. The difference comes from the typed array using [an offset and/or a length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array/Uint8Array) which essentially restrict the view to a slice of the buffer.

> And how can that be avoided (or corrected)?

Use the same offset and adjusted length:

```
function bytesToFloatArray(bytes) {
   return new Float32Array(bytes.buffer, bytes.byteOffset, bytes.byteLength/Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, I did not even look at the ArrayBuffer {432}, it had 4 bytes offset.

Comment: That's pretty complicated stuff.   It seems the more appropriate way to do the conversion would be _Float32Array.from(bytes)_

Comment: @WestCoastProjects Depends on what you want. Do you want to interpret the bytes as floats (in platform byte order), with the same underlying buffer? Or do you want to create a new buffer that is four times the size, and then take each byte from the input as an integer, convert that into a float, and write it into the new buffer?

Answer (score 0):

Post: @Bergi's answer is correct, I did not even look at the buffer Uint8 was created from.

I was not able to reproduce the behavior you had in chrome console, but you can always resort to using [DataView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView) to have fine grained control, something like this:

<sup>(beware of the endianness, and I did not test the code below, I might have done mistake in the byte orders)</sup>

```js
let test8 = new Uint8Array(400);
test8.forEach((d,i,a) => a[i] = 0xff * Math.random() | 0);

function c8to32(uint8, endian = false){ //big endian by default
    var cpBuff = new ArrayBuffer(uint8.length),
        view = new DataView(cpBuff);
    for (let i = 0,v = void(0); i < uint8.length; i += 4){
        if(!endian) { //big
            v =   uint8[i] << 24 
                | uint8[i + 1] << 16 
                | uint8[i + 2] << 8 
                | uint8[i + 3];
        } else { //little
           v =    uint8[i] 
                | uint8[i + 1] << 8 
                | uint8[i + 2] << 16
                | uint8[i + 3] << 24;
        }
        view.setFloat32(
            i,
            v,
            endian
        );
    }
    return cpBuff;
}

document.getElementById("resultbig").textContent = c8to32(test8).byteLength;
document.getElementById("resultlittle").textContent = c8to32(test8, true).byteLength;
```

```html
<div id="resultbig">test</div>
<div id="resultlittle">test</div>
```

Comment: that's pretty fancy - and I'll upvote for being a useful technique to see further. As you mentioned it does not directly answer the question so i'll not award.  btw for now i'm simply _slice_ ing away the first 8 elements ;)

Comment: np, np, however when I did  new Float32Array(test8.buffer), I would still get array of 100, not 108 in chrome. It might have something to do with the environment you are working with.